# How to use Spring Snapshots with Nexus Repository

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, nexus

We have no problem building Spring Boot RELEASE projects with our Nexus repository which proxies maven-central and use a maven-public group. A Spring Boot SNAPSHOT project won't build, because Maven cannot resolve the SNAPSHOT dependencies. Spring SNAPSHOTS get downloaded, but then we get this error message.

```
Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
in http://[host]:8081/repository/[snapshots] was cached in the local
repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
interval of [snapshots] has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Here are the settings:

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus-proxy-maven-central</id>
        <name>maven-central</name>
        <url>http://[host]/repository/maven-central</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven-public</id>
                <name>maven-public</name>
                <url>http://[host]/repository/maven-public</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>spring-milestone</id>
          <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven-public</id>
          <name>maven-public</name>
          <url>http://[host]/repository/maven-public</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>[snapshots]</id>
        <username>*</username>
        <password>*</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>[releases]</id>
        <username>*</username>
        <password>*</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>maven-public</id>
        <username>*</username>
        <password>*</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <username>*</username>
        <password>*</password>
</servers>
</settings>
```

The pom looks like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>[releases]</id>
    <url>https://[host]/repository/[releases]/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>[snapshots]</id>
    <url>https://[host]/repository/[snapshots]/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.spring.snapshot</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
      <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>[releases]</id>
      <name>[releases]</name>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
      <url>http://[host]/repository/[releases]</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>[snapshots]</id>
      <name>[snapshots]</name>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      <url>http://[host]/repository[snapshots]</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I've trying building with and without a Nexus proxy for Spring Snapshots, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is not publically available at http://repo.spring.io/snapshot at this time. The highest version available is 2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I was working with a Pivotal employee who must have access to higher build numbers earlier than the public. I backed my pom.xml down to 2.1.1.RELEASE and it worked.